# Optimize SUMIFS formula

Tags: arrays, excel, algorithm, optimization, sumifs

I basically have a super long formula that I need to shrink. So basically I have a pivot table that allows a manager to select two work locations or both and one to twelve months.

This is how the formula looks. Only thing that changes are cell `I` and `J->K`. Would I need to set this up in a array?

> =SUMIFS('owssvr(1)'!C:C,'owssvr(1)'!$IR:$IR,$I$3,'owssvr(1)'!$IQ:$IQ,'Summary KPI'!$J$2)+SUMIFS('owssvr(1)'!C:C,'owssvr(1)'!$IR:$IR,$I$4,'owssvr(1)'!$IQ:$IQ,'Summary KPI'!$J$2)+SUMIFS('owssvr(1)'!C:C,'owssvr(1)'!$IR:$IR,$I$5,'owssvr(1)'!$IQ:$IQ,'Summary KPI'!$J$2)+SUMIFS('owssvr(1)'!C:C,'owssvr(1)'!$IR:$IR,$I$6,'owssvr(1)'!$IQ:$IQ,'Summary KPI'!$J$2)+SUMIFS('owssvr(1)'!C:C,'owssvr(1)'!$IR:$IR,$I$7,'owssvr(1)'!$IQ:$IQ,'Summary KPI'!$J$2)+SUMIFS('owssvr(1)'!C:C,'owssvr(1)'!$IR:$IR,$I$8,'owssvr(1)'!$IQ:$IQ,'Summary KPI'!$J$2)+SUMIFS('owssvr(1)'!C:C,'owssvr(1)'!$IR:$IR,$I$9,'owssvr(1)'!$IQ:$IQ,'Summary KPI'!$J$2)+SUMIFS('owssvr(1)'!C:C,'owssvr(1)'!$IR:$IR,$I$10,'owssvr(1)'!$IQ:$IQ,'Summary KPI'!$J$2)+SUMIFS('owssvr(1)'!C:C,'owssvr(1)'!$IR:$IR,$I$11,'owssvr(1)'!$IQ:$IQ,'Summary KPI'!$J$2)+SUMIFS('owssvr(1)'!C:C,'owssvr(1)'!$IR:$IR,$I$12,'owssvr(1)'!$IQ:$IQ,'Summary KPI'!$J$2)+SUMIFS('owssvr(1)'!C:C,'owssvr(1)'!$IR:$IR,$I$13,'owssvr(1)'!$IQ:$IQ,'Summary KPI'!$J$2)+SUMIFS('owssvr(1)'!C:C,'owssvr(1)'!$IR:$IR,$I$14,'owssvr(1)'!$IQ:$IQ,'Summary KPI'!$J$2)+SUMIFS('owssvr(1)'!C:C,'owssvr(1)'!$IR:$IR,$I$3,'owssvr(1)'!$IQ:$IQ,'Summary KPI'!$K$2)+SUMIFS('owssvr(1)'!C:C,'owssvr(1)'!$IR:$IR,$I$4,'owssvr(1)'!$IQ:$IQ,'Summary KPI'!$K$2)+SUMIFS('owssvr(1)'!C:C,'owssvr(1)'!$IR:$IR,$I$5,'owssvr(1)'!$IQ:$IQ,'Summary KPI'!$K$2)+SUMIFS('owssvr(1)'!C:C,'owssvr(1)'!$IR:$IR,$I$6,'owssvr(1)'!$IQ:$IQ,'Summary KPI'!$K$2)+SUMIFS('owssvr(1)'!C:C,'owssvr(1)'!$IR:$IR,$I$7,'owssvr(1)'!$IQ:$IQ,'Summary KPI'!$K$2)+SUMIFS('owssvr(1)'!C:C,'owssvr(1)'!$IR:$IR,$I$8,'owssvr(1)'!$IQ:$IQ,'Summary KPI'!$K$2)+SUMIFS('owssvr(1)'!C:C,'owssvr(1)'!$IR:$IR,$I$9,'owssvr(1)'!$IQ:$IQ,'Summary KPI'!$K$2)+SUMIFS('owssvr(1)'!C:C,'owssvr(1)'!$IR:$IR,$I$10,'owssvr(1)'!$IQ:$IQ,'Summary KPI'!$K$2)+SUMIFS('owssvr(1)'!C:C,'owssvr(1)'!$IR:$IR,$I$11,'owssvr(1)'!$IQ:$IQ,'Summary KPI'!$K$2)+SUMIFS('owssvr(1)'!C:C,'owssvr(1)'!$IR:$IR,$I$12,'owssvr(1)'!$IQ:$IQ,'Summary KPI'!$K$2)+SUMIFS('owssvr(1)'!C:C,'owssvr(1)'!$IR:$IR,$I$13,'owssvr(1)'!$IQ:$IQ,'Summary KPI'!$K$2)+SUMIFS('owssvr(1)'!C:C,'owssvr(1)'!$IR:$IR,$I$14,'owssvr(1)'!$IQ:$IQ,'Summary KPI'!$K$2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This formula should give the same result

`=SUMPRODUCT(SUMIFS('owssvr(1)'!C:C,'owssvr(1)'!$IR:$IR,$I$3:$I$14,'owssvr(1)'!$IQ:$IQ,'Summary KPI'!$J$2:$K$2))`

Assuming you want to sum for all combinations then you can have at most one **vertical** and one **horizontal** range as criteria in `SUMIFS` (so $I$3:$I$14 and 'Summary KPI'!$J$2:$K$2 qualify as those).

`SUMIFS` then returns an array of 12x2 values (the same dimensions as your criteria) and `SUMPRODUCT` sums all those to get the correct result (used instead of `SUM` so that "array entry" is not required)